# Batch script to log in SSH server on Windows

Tags: shell, batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch script to log in into a SSH server and execute a few commands. The start command is:

`plink -ssh user@99.99.999.99`

Then I need to enter the User Name and Password like the image:

[image: ssh]

If I have the 'User Name' and 'Password' in two variables, how do I use them when it asks me for?

**[EDIT]**

last try was this:

```
(echo username
echo mypassword) | plink -ssh user@99.99.999.99
```

Output:

```
User Name:username
mypassword
Password:
```

The batch didn't "pressed" enter after inputing the username.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
plink -ssh -l $USER -pw $PASSWD
```

after setting environment variables

```
set USER=name
set PASSWD=secret
```

see http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html

Comment: I have to enter two logins and one password. In my case I am passing the first login (the SSH 'login as') before the ip (user@IP). It's like an extra login.

Comment: I don't really understand. On the server side you normally have a user account `username` where you want to login per ssh, so I would assume you just should `plink -ssh -l $USER -pw $PASSWD ipaddress`?!

Comment: Lets suppose I have to login twice. First the SSH login then the "system" login. The SSH login is fine because I only need the username (no password required). This is not about SSH, this is about auto inputing data.

Comment: I see, you have to solve it on server side then. You might want to have a look at [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).